# Configure $injector across entire test suite

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am mantaining an old project which has something like:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('project'));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('project.mocks'));
```

Before every single one of the 2000 tests involved.
Is it possible to just load this module once in the begining, I've tried:

```
beforeAll(angular.mock.module('project'));
beforeAll(angular.mock.module('project.mocks'));
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

`beforeAll` won't work because `ngMock` [uses `beforeEach`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.5/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L2816) to set up the injector for specs.

It would be possible to do

```
beforeAll(angular.mock.module('project'));
```

if `beforeEach` was replaced with `beforeAll` in `ngMock`. But it certainly shouldn't be so, because injectors should be torn down after each spec.

The problems with opinionated frameworks usually indicate that the design is flawed and conflicts with suggested usage scenario. In this case the problem is single Angular module. Angular applications aren't supposed to be tested like that, this is the reason why requested feature is missing and cannot be achieved smoothly.

When the entire application module is loaded, the units cannot be tested in isolation, this contrasts with the concept of unit testing. Reusability and testability are the concerns for multiple Angular modules.

When application units are extremely split up to separate modules like that

```
angular.module('project', ['project.some', 'ui.router', ...]);

angular.module('project.some', ['project.some.someCtrl', 'project.some.someSvc', 'ui.router']);

angular.module('project.some.someCtrl', []).controller('SomeController', ...);
```

the modules are aren't restricted on how they affect each other in tests, they can be loaded and mocked in any combination.